# A windows app starting and receiving a fil with dag-and-drop c++

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop

I have updated to vs2019.
I have been unable to find out how set up input argument when debugging?
That setup has moved and I can't find it in the menu system, where is it ??
Using c++;

Answer (score 0):

Found it: In the Solution Explorer, Right click on project name to open menu, open Properties, select Configuration Properties, Debugging, Command Arguments

Comment: BTW, this method has worked in all versions of Visual Studio that I can remember.